# Explanation for the java code?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

What does this code mean:

```
table = new JTable(){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Which part(s) of it do you not understand?

Comment: People really are abusing the downvote... It's a legitimate question...

Comment: @Luchian, it was me who downvoted. It's not clear exactly *what* the OP needs to have explained. Does he not know what a `JTable` is? Does he not understand the "inline" definition of a method, ie. the *syntax*? Does he not understand what the particular code *does*? If it's the latter, some context around that code bit might also have been helpful.

Comment: public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return true;
        }
This Part of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as:

```
class MyJTable extends JTable
{
    public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }
}
table = new MyJTable;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm), which in this case has provided an implementation for JTable's isCellEditable method that always returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever arguments you pass to `isCellEditable` of this instance of JTable, it will always return `true`. This is not the default behavior in `JTable`, so you're overriding this behavior of your instance.

(If you meant "why would anyone do that", it should get you a JTable in which every cell is editable)